# Unknown escape sequence

Tags: c

I am trying to printf a string that shows a temperature table 
`printf("TABLE 24A (20\°C)");`

The degree sign is a constant I have defined as `0xDF` so the the string looks like this: `"TABLE 24A (20\xDF C)"`

This works but looks incorrect because of the space between the `\xDF` and the `C`. 
If I remove the space the compiler issues a warning *hex escape sequence out of range*.

If I modify the string to `"TABLE 24A (20\xDF\C)"` I get the correct result but the compiler issues warning *unknown escape sequence: '\C'*

Is there a way to get rid of the warnings but lose the space between the two characters?

Comment: What about `\u00DFC`?

Comment: have you tried using %c for the \xDF?

Comment: The unicode option does not work in my c compiler. It gives the following **warning: universal character names are only valid in C++ and C99**

Both octal and combining two adjacent string literals work well, thank you for the help!

Regards
Richard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\x` escape sequences consume as many adjacent hex digits as possible. The `C` is being parsed as a hex digit.

With `\x`, you could combine two adjacent string literals.

```
printf("**TABLE 24A (20\xDF""C)**");
```

Or use a `\unnnn` Unicode escape, which is limited to four hex characters.

```
printf("**TABLE 24A (20\u00DFC)**");
```

Or octal `\nnn`:

```
printf("**TABLE 24A (20\337C)**");
```

Answer (score 9):

You can take advantage of the fact that consecutive string literals are automatically concatenated:

```
 printf("**TABLE 24A (20\xDF" "C)**");
```

This prevents the parser from consuming more characters for the escape sequence than you want.

You could also pass in the character as a parameter and use the `%c` format specifier to print it:

```
printf("**TABLE 24A (20%cC)**", '\xDF');
```